# Stack overflow occurring on first procedure call inside recursive procedure

Tags: java, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I am getting a stack overflow error due to a bug I understand, but what I do not understand is why the stack overflow is occurring on the first procedure in the recursive procedure instead of on the call to the recursive procedure.

In a method to solve a sudoku puzzle here is the recursive segment (the bolded text is the recursive call:

```
    System.out.print(""); <= stack overflow occurs here
    int[] move_quality_sorted_keys = Sorting_jsc.RadixSort_unsigned_1( move_quality );
    for( int xPossibleMove = 1; xPossibleMove <= ctPossibleMoves; xPossibleMove++ ){
        int xMove = move_quality_sorted_keys[ctPossibleMoves - xPossibleMove + 1];
        int[][] new_grid = new int[10][10];
        for( int xRow = 1; xRow <= 9; xRow++ )
            for( int xColumn = 1; xColumn <= 9; xColumn++ )
                new_grid[xRow][xColumn] = grid[xRow][xColumn];
        new_grid[move_row[xMove]][move_column[xMove]] = move_value[xMove];
        int[][] solution = solveSudokuGrid( new_grid );
        if( solution != null ) return solution;
    }
```

The stack overflow error is the following (note it is occurring on the System.out.print() statement):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:221)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:525)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2458)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
    at Euler100.solveSudokuGrid(Euler100.java:2467)
```

I would expect the stack overflow to occur on the call to solveSudokuGrid, not on the print statement. Why is it?

Comment: What are you printing there exactly?

Comment: @AndyFaizan nothing, the print statement is just there to demonstrate that the stack overflow is occurring on the first call inside the recursive procedure, instead of on the call to the recursive procedure itself.

Comment: How deep is the stack when it blows up?  The error is reported when the stack becomes too big to be further extended.  If the very first statement in your routine is a print call (which extends the stack further), that's where the error will be detected.

Answer (score 5):

Look at it this way: each time you call `System.out.println` you push 4 (or more) additional stack frames on to the top of your stack as you see in the error.  These are then popped off the stack before you call your own function recursively.  The depth of the stack therefore goes like this:

- your code, 1 level
- println, 5 levels
- your code, 2 levels
- println, 6 levels
- your code, 3 levels
- println, 7 levels
- ...
- your code, n levels
- println, n + 4 levels
- your code, n + 1 levels
- ...

Assuming each level takes the same amount of stack memory (which isn't actually true but is probably close enough for this kind of analysis) it should be quite obvious that for any particular limit on the size of the stack, the println code will break through it first.

All that is actually required is for the other procedure to use more memory on the stack than your procedure and this will always happen.  If it uses less, it might still happen (because for any given level it is called before your code), and presumably as the println call is only there to demonstrate this, the radix sort code you have a call to in the next line was previously triggering the behaviour.  It presumably uses more stack space than your own method (which seems quite likely; you only have 6 local variables and most of your expressions are very simple).

Comment: Yep, unless the amount of stack needed for one frame of `solveSudokuGrid` is greater than the stack required for the 4 (or more) methods invoked by `print` (not likely) then the failure will always be detected in the `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because you exceed the stack bound at that point.  [wiki here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

It seems that System.out.println will eventually call BufferedWriter.write which is also a recursive function that will eventually cause the stackoverflow.